# Comparing metrics with mean and standard deviation

Tags: hypothesis-testing, model-comparison

I have been running some experiments for a problem using different models. Those experiment run on 10 different datasets and each of them yields a value for RMSE.

After all the 10 experiments are finished I get a mean value and standard deviation for the RMSE of that model. I repeat this process for all the models and end up with some mean values and std that I should compare to choose the best/bests ones. Obviously I am not interested in the result on each dataset but on the average performance of the model in all datasets.

For example I may get this mean RMSE results for let's say 3 models (std in parenthesis):

```
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|      Model 1        |     Model 2      |      Model 3     | 
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
|     5.53 (0.12)     |    5.61 (0.10)   |    5.69 (0.10)   |
|---------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

It is clear that the model 1 gets the bests mean results (the lower the better) but when taking into account the standard deviation, model 2 is really close to it. Model 3 is a bit off.

I know there must be some way of doing this statically, proving that both model 1 and model 2 get (almost) the same results. I thought about using z-test or t-test but I don't know how to fit that here.

Any idea how can I proceed to select the best models taking into account the standard deviation?

Comment: I have no experience viewing RMSEs as data in a 2-sample test, but even assuming RMSEs are nearly normally distributed (doubtful), a t test would show no difference between 1 and 2. However, failure to reject hypothesis "$H_0:$ same" does not 'prove' they are the same. // Seeing the 20 actual RMSEs might help.

Comment: @BruceET I guess you could assume that the RMSE that you get for each model is normally distributed? I could post some results but I don't think that would change anything